# Replace an item in a $firebaseArray

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to figure out how I can update an item in a firebase array. I display the array like this:

```
tr(ng-repeat="client in clients")
    td
        button(ng-click="addClient(client)")
```

The problem is that my `addClient(client)` method actually opens up a modal window allowing the user to make the modifications. Typically what I do in this case is I clone the `client` object that is passed to the modal window so that the original object is not modified until the users closes the modal window like so:

```
app.controller('modalEditClient', ($scope, $modalInstance, client) ->
    $scope.client = angular.clone(client)
```

When I return from the modal window, I thought that I could do something like this:
    $scope.clients.$save(newClient)

But this fails because `newClient` is actually the cloned version of the original client.

My question is: What is the best way to do this? Should I just remove the original client and just `$add(newClient)`? Or is there a way to just update the data on the original object with the data from the new object?

Comment: Is this a "modal" as in, it is actually in the same DOM, or a popup window, as in, it opens a new tab/window? if it is in the same DOM, you'll need to explain why we're cloning objects instead of working on the original reference. If it's a popup, I guess I'd have to draw the line at 1999 for any sort of coding strategy I'm willing to support and just say no.

Comment: Yes, this is in a modal window. I clone the object so that the original on doesn't update as well (in case the user actually dismisses the modal window). Make sense?

Comment: Most likely, angular.clone() is removing $id, which is essential to determining which record the data belongs to.

Comment: It is not. The problem, I think, lies in the way that $firebaseArray saves. Because I'm cloning an item in the array, the original object is not changed. Therefore when I call $firebaseArray.$save(clonedItem), it actually saves the original object which was not actually modified at all.

Comment: Apply the changes back to the original item with angular.extend()?

Comment: That was it! Thanks! If you want to put that as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: You should feel free to post the solution. I'll upvote it and you can accept your own answer (after a short wait)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting from Kato's comments

Because I'm cloning an object in a modal window, `$firebaseArray` doesn't know about it. Therefore, when I modify the clone, and need to write back to the original firebase object, I have to apply the changes back to the original object.

`angular.extend(original_object, new_object)` solves this. Then I can save the data back to firebase using `$firebaseArray` as usual:

`$scope.items.$save(original_object)`

Comment: Note that angular.extend() probably won't copy $value, so when working with primitives, you'd want to set $value on the original object vs. trying to use extend (which is hopefully intuitive since we aren't "extending" a primitive value)